# Neo4j - failed to start after upgrading from 2.2.5 to 2.3.0

Tags: neo4j

This is the error I am getting.

The database is empty, no graph.db directory.

All server properties files are the same with those used for version 2.2.5.

Here is the content of console.log :

```
15:56:31.972 [main] DEBUG i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2015-10-26 15:56:33.932+0000 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2015-10-26 15:56:33.934+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.d
atabase.LifecycleManagingDatabase@36a005fb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see atta
ched cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@36
a005fb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.Lifecycle
ManagingDatabase@36a005fb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause except
ion.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.ja
va:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagi
ngDatabase@36a005fb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:538)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)
    ... 3 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFa
ctory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFacto
ry.java:143)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:
43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFacto
ry.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95
)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:528)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recover
y@2591d7e3' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:510)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you activated the `allow_store_upgrade` configuration in neo4j.properties ?
I there something in data/graph.db/messages.log ?

Comment: The folder graph.db does not exists:
ubuntu@ip-10-92-135-77:~/data/neo4j-data$ ls -lrt
total 0
That parameter allow_store_upgrade is set to true:
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
allow_store_upgrade=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was something mach simpler. I had to change the parameter org.neo4j.server.database.location=/home/ubuntu/data/neo4j-data/graph.db since the default location provided by the installer was wrong.

Comment: Did you use something like `apt-get` to install Neo4j?  I often download Neo4j directly from neo4j.com with curl and unzip it where I want it so that I don't have to worry about where it was installed.  Since Neo4j is self contained you can have everything in one place (or not, if that's what you want, as you found from the `database.location` setting)

Comment: Yes, I am always using apt-get since I don't know how to download with curl and unzip.

Comment: Understood.  It's pretty straightforward.  You can run `curl http://host/path > download_path` and then `tar -xvzf neo4j-community-2.3.0.tar.gz` (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file )